# update stock quantity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im having trouble to update my stock quantity from stock table based on size from the cart table

stock

```
| size | quantity |
| -----| ---------|
| XS   | 100      |
| S    | 100      |
| M    | 100      |
| L    | 100      |
| XL   | 100      |
| 2XL  | 100      |
| 3XL  | 100      |
```

cart

```
| size | quantity |
| -----| ---------|
| XS   | 3        |
| 2XL  | 5        |
```

after i run my code the stock table will become like this

stock

```
| size | quantity |
| -----| ---------|
| XS   | 97       |
| S    | 0        |
| M    | 0        |
| L    | 0        |
| XL   | 0        |
| 2XL  | 95       |
| 3XL  | 0        |
```

it should be like this

stock

```
| size | quantity |
| -----| ---------|
| XS   | 97       |
| S    | 100      |
| M    | 100      |
| L    | 100      |
| XL   | 100      |
| 2XL  | 95       |
| 3XL  | 100      |
```

my code

```
include "db_connect.php";
//update stock quantity
  $stockquery = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE stock SET Quantity = Quantity - (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM cart WHERE size = stock.Size)");

  if(mysqli_query($connect, $stockquery))  
  {  
      echo ' stock Successful';  
  }
  else
  {
      echo ' stock Failed';
  }
```

the output is also is stock failed

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this related to HTML?

Comment: "the output is also is stock failed" - have you tried to check **why** this is the case? Usually, MySQL provides error messages in case a query fails

Comment: @NicoHaase it does not show why

Comment: Have you even tried to check for a reason? Does that query work properly if you run it using phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench, or any other tool?

Answer (score 2):

You need in multiple-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE stock 
JOIN ( SELECT size, SUM(quantity) quantity
       FROM cart
       GROUP BY size ) total USING (size)
SET stock.quantity = stock.quantity - total.quantity
```

Comment: this change my XS to 3 instead of 97 and 2XL to 5 instead of 95

Comment: @MuizYusri Oops.. sorry. Fixed.

Comment: it works. thank you so much. but the output is still stock failed. do you know why?

Comment: @MuizYusri Please one problem - one question. Especially when another problem is not related.

Comment: alright. im sorry im new to this community

Comment: This also has the advantage that it only updates sizes that are actually in the cart.